# What's the difference between <<EOF and <<\EOF heredocs in shell

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have noticed several distinction between them:

Inside a `<<EOF` heredoc, new values can not be assigned to variables:

```
bash <<EOF
s=fds
echo $s
EOF
```

will print empty line, where

```
bash <<\EOF
s=fds
echo $s
EOF
```

will print the value of the variable `s`.

Global variables can be accessed within `<<EOF` but not within `<<\EOF` (with `export` it is possible to access variables inside `<<\EOF`):

```
s=fds
bash <<EOF
echo $s
EOF
```

will print the value `fds`, where,

```
s=fds
bash <<\EOF
echo $s
EOF
```

will print empty line.

So what are the differences between them and what is the legitimate documented behavior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04):

> If any character in *word* is quoted, the delimiter shall be formed by performing quote removal on *word*, and the here-document lines shall not be expanded. Otherwise, the delimiter shall be the *word* itself.

So the `<<EOF` version has the shell expand all variables *before* running the here doc contents and the `<<\EOF` (or `<<'EOF'` or `<<EO'F'` etc.) versions don't expand the contents (which lets `bash` in this case do that work).

Try it with `cat` instead of `bash` for a clearer view on what is happening.

Also with `printf '[%s]\n' "$s"` and/or possibly `bash -x` instead of `bash`:

```
$ bash -x <<EOF
s=fds
printf '[%s]\n' "$s"
EOF
+ s=fds
+ printf '[%s]\n' ''
[]

$ bash -x <<\EOF
s=fds
printf '[%s]\n' "$s"
EOF
+ s=fds
+ printf '[%s]\n' fds
[fds]
```

Comment: This is the part that made it clear to me: `So the <<EOF version has the shell expand all variables before running the here doc contents and the <<\EOF (or <<'EOF' or <<EO'F' etc.) versions don't expand the contents (which lets bash in this case) do that work.` thnks...Etan....

Answer (score 1):

Documentation: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents

In your first example the delimiter is unquoted, so variable expansion occurs and it's like you're running the code

```
echo "s=fds
echo $s" | bash
```

which expands `$s` in the current shell, where it's empty. So the new shell sees

```
s=fds
echo
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) & [bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/) in particular about [redirections](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Documents):

> The format of here-documents is:

```
<<[-]word
        here-document
delimiter
```

> No parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic
>   expansion, or filename expansion is performed on word. If any
>   characters in word are quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote
>   removal on word, and the lines in the here-document are not expanded.
>   If word is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to
>   parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion,
>   the character sequence \newline is ignored, and ‘\’ must be used to
>   quote the characters ‘\’, ‘$’, and ‘`’.